# Errors when referenace android project to ui test project Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, automated-tests

I have an intruder problem. I have created a xamarin form solution with monoandroid 8.1 and .net standard 2.0 and everything was going fine, but once I added UI test project and add android project as reference I saw 4 errors and when I built it build was successful but the error was still visible.

When I build it in app center it fails and shows me these 4 errors: 
[errors list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6sEJ.png)

Log from app center

> 2018-06-11T10:26:21.6746020Z NU1201: Project UserLogin.Android is not
>   compatible with net471 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1). Project
>   UserLogin.Android supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)

Comment: looks like you created a wrong test project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/uitest-and-test-cloud?tabs=vswin

Comment: 3- Add a project reference from the UITest project to the Xamarin.Android project:,
when i reach to this point errors appear :/

Comment: @MuhammadAbuMandor I also see this error. Did you ever fix it?

Comment: Yes, with work around, i created project with old version of xamarin  then i cloned it in new version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem after update visual studio to latest version